# Why is "index_" prefix added to class and id selectors in webpack imported CSS

Tags: css, webpack, css-loader

While importing a regular CSS file with webpack, it successfully imports and applies the CSS, but it only does so for element selectors. I discovered that the problem is caused by a **index_** prefix that is added to class and id selectors in the imported CSS blob from the style-loader.

[image]

In the source map, you can see that the original file does not have these prefixes.

[image]

So the question remains. Why are these prefixes added?

Comment: what does your config look like? also [this may be relevant](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#scope)

Comment: Please show the webpack config - it's probably configured to add the prefix

Comment: @rlemon , thanks for pointing out. I have modules: true configured in webpack config. I have included the answer in the question.

Comment: @DonnyVerduijn, instead of editing your original question, put the answer that you found as an answer. It seems odd answering your own question but its very helpful for future readers and shows people that this question is answered and not still open.

Comment: @Ian It makes sense when you think about it. I will create a separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the docs of css-loader, it is clear this behavior is created by passing `modules: true` as an option to `css-loader` in the webpack configuration. This behavior can be overridden by using`:global(selector)` notation with all class and id selectors.

**From the docs:**

> With :local (without brackets) local mode can be switched on for this
>   selector. **:global(.className) can be used to declare an explicit
>   global selector.** With :global (without brackets) global mode can be
>   switched on for this selector.